# How do I prevent directories mounted with 'bind' from appearing on 'Devices' on nautilus?

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, mount, directory, bind

I have these lines in the fstab

```
# binds
/media/DataNtfs/Music           /home/can/Music                  none    rw,bind 
/media/DataNtfs/Pictures        /home/can/Pictures               none    rw,bind 
/media/DataNtfs/Downloads       /home/can/Downloads              none    rw,bind 
/media/DataNtfs/Documents       /home/can/Documents              none    rw,bind 
/media/DataNtfs/Backups         /home/can/Backups                none    rw,bind 
/media/DataNtfs/Notes           /home/can/Notes                  none    rw,bind 
/media/DataNtfs/Other           /home/can/Other                  none    rw,bind 
/media/DataNtfs/Packages        /home/can/Packages               none    rw,bind 
/media/DataNtfs/Photos          /home/can/Photos                 none    rw,bind 
/media/DataNtfs/Videos          /home/can/Videos                 none    rw,bind 
/media/DataNtfs/WorkSpace       /home/can/WorkSpace              none    rw,bind
```

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: you can add screenshots now, if you like.

Comment: add to /etc/fstab `x-gvfs-show` option to each drive you want to hide in nautilus

Answer (score 1):

- Mount them elsewhere. `/media` is automatically added. Mount them in `/mnt` and they will not appear (unless someone made a udev rule to do so). Nowadays everything seems to be mounted in /media but it used to be so that /mnt was for internal disks and /media for removable discs. No-one is stopping you from using /mnt!
- Adding the `x-gvfs-show` as Arhimed pointed out in comments does not seem to work. This [bug #1011257](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1011257) affects both 12.10 and 13.04 and is due to a package that needs to be updated: util-linux.
- Besides that you can cancel all automounting from dconf-editor:

[image]

Comment: They are not harddisks and not mounted in /media. They are directories and 'bind'ed to home directory.

Comment: So? Like I said: change `/media/DataNtfs/Music ` to `/mnt/DataNtfs/Music` and they will not show in Nautilus Devices pane. Anything in `/media` is automatically 'mounted' by Nautilus unless you change the dconf setting.

Comment: I understand you. I upgraded 13.04 and its okay now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded 13.04 and they gone. I think developers take that as a wrong feature instead of a bug, and they fix it in 13.04. I suggest you to upgrade.

[image: This is my home directory]

I liked new look of the nautilus.